# spring batch Classifier: Writer must be open before it can be written to

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm new to spring and which to split database to 3 csv files.

My actual code: (I'm not using xml and don't want to)

I've tried many solutions but nothing work.

```
    class MyClassifier {

        @Classifier
        public String classify(Pojo Pojo) {
return String.valueOf(Pojo.getYear());
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "PojoWriter") 
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<Pojo> itemWriter() throws Exception {
        BackToBackPatternClassifier classifier = new BackToBackPatternClassifier();
        classifier.setRouterDelegate(new MyClassifier());

        classifier.setMatcherMap(new HashMap<String, FlatFileItemWriter<? super Pojo>>() {
            FlatFileItemWriter<Pojo> writerH;
            {
            writerH = writer("2017",null,null); put("2017", writerH); writerH.close(); 
            writerH = writer("2018",null,null); put("2018", writerH); writerH.close();
            writerH = writer("2019",null,null); put("2019", writerH); writerH.close();
            }
        });
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Pojo> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Pojo>();
        writer.setClassifier(classifier);
        return writer;
    }
```

I classify with year, and 3 files are created

```
//  @Bean(name = "FlatWriter") 
//  @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Pojo> writer( final String name,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromId']}") final String fromId,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toId']}") final String toId) throws Exception {

        FlatFileItemWriter<Pojo> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Pojo>();

        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(name + ".csv"));
        writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
        writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
        writer.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
            @Override
            public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                writer.write(
                        "Id, number, name");
            }
        });
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Pojo>() {
            {

                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Pojo>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "Id", "number", "name" });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Foo, Pojo>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor()) 
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
                .flow(step1()).end().build();   
    }
```

Parameters :
    `@Component`
    `@EnableBatchProcessing`
    `@Configurable`
 and `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`

stacktrace of error :

> 2019-07-15 11:13:44.666 ERROR 12632 --- [   Spring Shell] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step1 in job exportUserJob
>
> org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
>           at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:255) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.write(ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.java:66) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
>           at com.viviane.commands.CsvGenerator.transactionalCsvBuilder(CsvGenerator.java:700) [classes/:na]
>           at com.viviane.commands.Scanner.createFiles(Scanner.java:93) [classes/:na]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.invoke(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:64) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.execute(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:57) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.shell.core.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:127) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:533) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:179) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]

Comment: Don't call `writer.open` and `writerH.close`, Spring Batch will do it.

Comment: Removing writer.open and writerH.close do nothing. Exactly the same error.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine. I removed Classifier and changed to a Partitioner. It succesfully create the 3 filename, but now I don't know how to handle the classification with year and write only the fromId toId part.

Comment: If you go the partitioning route, you don't need the classifier anymore. Give each partition a year and use a regular writer.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, thank you, that's what i've done. It's a long process because all years sequentials and not parallels, but it work.